# Find all *.tpl files in /template folder and chmod them 666 recursively

Tags: linux, permissions, find, chmod

I need to find all *.tpl files in /template folder and chmod them recursively. What does chmoding files recursively mean, by the way? I guess it will find all *.tpl files and chmod them to 666. How would this be recursive?

I have this and it does not work:

```
find /template -type f \( -iname "*.tpl" \) | xargs chmod 666
```

Is there any better way of doing something like this?

Comment: find template -type f -iname "*.tpl" | xargs chmod 666 - Would this be good? This would be run from the directory in which the template directory is in. I run it and it seemed to work.

Comment: Seems like you have answered your own question :)

Comment: It worked with that, but it does not work on other directories, and I need to do the same thing. I am getting errors like "chmod: missing operand afer '666', things like this.

Comment: From the error you stated, that makes me think that nothing was passed to `chmod`. Are you sure you have ".tpl" files in where you searched?

Answer (score 0):

Going further off of your answer to your own question :), you could also do the following in a script, although your one-liner works. I have added some code so you could rerun this script to look into different directories as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
  echo "Please provide a directory to the script... For example: ./thisScript /directoryTosearch"
  exit 2
fi

for i in $(find $1 -type f -iname "*.tpl") ; do
  echo "Changing permissions on ${i}"
  chmod 666 ${i}
done
```

I through in an echo so that you will have a nice output displayed to your screen stating what files were changed.

Comment: Well, I may try that, since the other one is not working. I would like to find the best and most standard way though. I am still learning this, making notes. I want to figure it out, and not just do it and move on.